# onScroll event not triggering while scrolling to the specific div (Next js)

Tags: javascript, next.js, scroll

I want to fetch data while a specific div enters into the user screen (using Next js on a SSR page)
I try to use the onScroll event on the div but it does not trigger. Any hints ?

```js
function handleScroll() {
    console.log("scrolled to element")
}

<section onScroll={handleScroll} className={`${styles.notifTop} marginTop2 container`}>
  <p className={styles.notifTitle}>Des actions plutôt que des mots !</p>
  <p className={`${styles.notifParagraph}`}>La somme de <span className="fontWeight400">petites actions individuelles</span> permettra d’accomplir les <span className="fontWeight400">grands défis collectifs</span> que nous ne pouvons plus ignorer.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function handleScroll() {
    console.log("scrolled to element")
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div onScroll="handleScroll()" className={`${styles.notifTop} marginTop2 container`}>
  <p className={styles.notifTitle}>Des actions plutôt que des mots !</p>
  <p className={`${styles.notifParagraph}`}>La somme de <span className="fontWeight400">petites actions individuelles</span> permettra d’accomplir les <span className="fontWeight400">grands défis collectifs</span> que nous ne pouvons plus ignorer.</p>
</div>
```

Instead of `section` tag you have to use the `div` tag, `onScroll` event will work as you can see the above code.

```
function handleScroll() {
    console.log("scrolled to element")
}

<div onScroll={handleScroll} className={`${styles.notifTop} marginTop2 container`}>
  <p className={styles.notifTitle}>Des actions plutôt que des mots !</p>
  <p className={`${styles.notifParagraph}`}>La somme de <span className="fontWeight400">petites actions individuelles</span> permettra d’accomplir les <span className="fontWeight400">grands défis collectifs</span> que nous ne pouvons plus ignorer.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not working however... If I replace with a onClick, everything works fine but the onScroll does not trigger... is it because of Next.js ?